# Automation Server not Installed

Tags: crystal-reports, report, reporting

How can I solve an error stating the following?

> Crystal.CRPE.Application Automation Server not Installed

[image]

Comment: I found my way to solve this case...

Comment: What I need to do is by running some ocx files to register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Already Solved.
I just need to install some ocx files that are used in my company.